# Handle microphone inputs in c #

Tags: c#, input, streaming, microphone

I searched on Google, but I did not find much information about it. I was wondering if anyone had experience so that they knew a **proper** way to get data input from a microphone and also know how to play it. What I would like to do is a typical streaming app in C#, which takes audio from the microphone and sends it on the client application. I await advice, thank you.

Comment: If I understand do you need to Speech To Text functionality?

Comment: @OktamYaqubov actually I want to develop an application to talk on the net with connected people, a bit like Skype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those still interested I found the NAudio library really interesting: https://github.com/naudio/NAudio

Answer (score 1):

There're many source codes available if you can use google and bing... If you want to build this application with C# programming language, then you need to know some basics of Network Programming in C#.

1. If you want build a program like voice chat. You will need grab the audio from the microphone using some technalogies like DirectSound, UDP packets and etc.
2. If you want build a video streaming application you can use several ways to get video streaming/conferencing with .net easily.
   Use of plain Windows Media Encoder components, RTC Clients, voice/SIP, Sockets and etc.
   So you have wide choice of managed technologies here. Another thing is Live Meeting at which you had no chance to take good look yet.